# testID & accessibilityLabel for Android and IOS

Tags: mobile, automation, appium

I'm starting new project written in React Native. Would like to advice developers for writing correct & custom locators which later will be used as an Appium elements.

As I'm digging depper the topic I'm kinda lost with the ideas of both: testID and accessibilityLabel.

On official Appium web it is written:
*"The solution here is to make sure not just to use the testID attribute on important components, but also to set the accessibilityLabel attribute, to ensure that the element is always findable via Appium's 'accessibility id' locator strategy.* "

On the other hand I've found a phrase: *For iOS in React Native you can use testID, for android as far as I know accessibilityLabel the only way."*

**What will be the perfect way to name attribute of locators for both Android and IOS Appium automation?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both to make it work on android and iOS.

The simplest naming convention to use is **prefix_id**. Here, the prefix can be your class name or value passed from the parent container. This way you will be able to give unique names to the same elements on a single screen. For example, let's say you created an input box component. This component will be used in your container multiple times and you need unique ids. In this case, just pass prefix and both input and labels will be given unique ids. For testing

There is another layer of complication here. AccesibilityLabel is also used in voice-overs and you might want to add another meaningful text there, in release builds. Hence, It's better to create an injector class that handles all of this. If you require platform-specific handling then that can be done in this injector class.

You will also require to mark accessible prop as false for test builds. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6560